# Polymer: perform animated-pages transition on polymer element

Tags: polymer

Say I've got one polymer app `test-app`, one regular div `div-a`, and one polymer element `page-a`.

Now I'm trying to build a `animated-pages`, which contains `div-a` and `page-a`

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">

<link rel="import" href="../page-a/page-a.html">

<polymer-element name="test-app" flex vertical layout>

  <template>
      <core-animated-pages
        selected="{{selected}}"
        transitions="cross-fade"
      >
        <section name="div-a">
          <div cross-fade>
            <span>div-a</span>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section name="page-a">
          <page-a cross-fade></page-a>
        </section>

      </core-animated-pages>

  </template>

  <script src="./test-app.js"></script>

</polymer-element>
```

The problem is: when performing the transition, the animation on `div-a` works fine, but the one on `page-a` doesnot work. Instead of fading in, the `page-a` just suddenly appears.

Another strange point is: if I change `transitions="cross-fade"` into `transitions="cross-fade-all"`, and remove other `cross-fade` defined on `div` and `page-a`, both transitions work find.

Any idea?

Comment: Just wonder if you have set `overflow: hidden` in your `page-a` element?

Comment: @JustinXL Well... nope, what's that about? Additionally, I tried but nothing happened

Comment: What I have learnt is that if a custom Polymer element has this style, applying the `cross-fade` directly on it will not work. But if you wrap your element within another `div` and set the animation attribute on the `div` then it works.

Comment: @JustinXL Thanks, btw where did you learnt that from? where can i find any detailed docs or articles about this animated-pages thing?

Comment: I had a similar issue before and resolved it by changing that style. You can try removing your css one by one n see if it helps.

Comment: I'm just learning these polymer elements, so currently I got no styles at all. :(

Comment: Hmm that's weird, can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-fade doesn't work directly on elements that have `overflow: hidden` set.